# MS Outlook sets start and end times one minute later with iCal plugin

Tags: expresso, ical

Thread title explains it all. With output like this:

```
DTSTAMP:20130226T150037
DTSTART:20130226T150037
DTEND:20130226T170037
```

Outlook will set the start time as 3:01pm and the end time as 5:01pm. Probably a bug with Outlook but I thought I'd ask here anyway to see if anyone else had reported a similar problem.

Comment: Looking at the seconds (far right), its probably rounding them up to the nearest minute. Let me have a go at replicating this.